# How do I get these specific pathlines to nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have four nodes, one parent and three children. I am trying to link with these specific arrow paths:

[image: path lines I want]

I have only just started working with the tikz package and my code so far looks like:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
,node distance =5mm
,>=latex'
,block/.style ={
    ,draw
    ,minimum height = 10mm
    ,minimum width =28mm
    ,align=center
    }
,every path/.style={->} %sets arrow style
]
\node [block]   (main) {Main};
\node [block, below=of main] (second)   {Second};  
\node [block, left=of second] (first)   {First};
\node [block, right=of second] (third)  {Third};

\draw (main) to (first);
\draw (main) to (second);
\draw (main) to (third);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

I tried using -| but that only produced one corner in the path, not the two I need. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
,node distance =5mm
,>=latex'
,block/.style ={
    ,draw
    ,minimum height = 10mm
    ,minimum width =28mm
    ,align=center
    }
,every path/.style={->} %sets arrow style
]
\node [block]   (main) {Main};
\node [block, below=of main] (second)   {Second};
\node [block, left=of second] (first)   {First};
\node [block, right=of second] (third)  {Third};

\draw ([xshift=-3mm] main.south) -- + (0,-2mm) -| (first);
\draw (main) to (second);
\draw ([xshift= 3mm] main.south) -- + (0,-2mm) -| (third);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Ah great! Thankyou @Zarko - can I also ask what is the role of the  "-- + (0,-2mm)" operation?

Comment: in used case: "draw from given coordinate 2mm down". it is relative coordinate. see *13.4 Relative and Incremental Coordinates, tikz and pgf manual, page 143*.